# Dropwizard hiding field in json

Tags: jackson, dropwizard

What's the best way to hide a field on a model in Dropwizard?  (If I want to be able to deserialize the field via Jackson, but hide it when serialization)

For example, if I have the following model:

```
class User {
  private String secret;
  private String username;
}
```

I want to be able to create a User with a secret via calling `new ObjectMapper().readValue()`, but I want to hide the secret field it when it's serialized into JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Add `@JsonIgnore` annotation before the property

Or you can add `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation and specify the fields which are to be excluded

```
public class Foo{
     @JsonIgnore
     private String bar;
     ...
}
```

or

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "bar" })
public class Foo {
    private String bar;

...
}
```

or if you want to ignore this field only on serialization, and not on deserialization then

```
public class Foo{

     private String bar;
     ...
     @JsonIgnore
     public String getBar(){
           return bar;
     }

     public void setBar(String bar){
           this.bar = bar;
     }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Adding the @JsonIgnore annotation would mean this field is completely ignored by Jackson, which is not my intention.  I want to still be able to deserialize the field (read it in from a JSON).  Just don't want it to show during serialization.

Comment: then add @JsonIgnore annotation on the getter method only. Not on the declaration of field.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it only during seriazliation add `@JsonIgnore` annotation to property getter.

```
class User {
  @JsonProperty
  private String secret;
  @JsonProperty
  private String username;
  @JsonIgnore
  public String getSecret(){
      return secret;
  }
  public void setSecret(String secret){
      this.secret = secret;
  }
  ...
}
```